# We built a book search app in class .. how can I click on one result and link to google maps to bring up nearest book store

Tags: android, maps

We built a book app (BookMaster General) where you can search any book using open library.  However I need to add the ability to show the closest book store when you click on the title of a book.  How do I accomplish this?  I have used the Android API for locator but never like this.

This link shows the app we built ... http://www.raywenderlich.com/78578/android-tutorial-for-beginners-part-3

Instead of it showing the book cover it opens up maps with the closest bookstore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an intent like this:

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=bookstore");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Take a look at the Categorical Search in the google maps android api documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents

Comment: so ...=bookstore") would search google maps for bookstores nearby correct?  I am still a little lost on what file I put this in since I have 3 java classes in this project.  I am assuming I can eliminate putting in my JSON class since that is all about the book search/query.